# Prevent scrolling of parent element from child element

Tags: css

divA and divB are two  elements.

I have divA that has twice the window width as width and twice the window height as height. I have set overflow as hidden as I do not want the user to be able to scroll the div.
However, I noticed that if I place a smaller div (divB) on the top of divA with position absolute,and if the user places his cursor over divB, then he is able to scroll divA.

How can I prevent the undesired scrolling on divA?

```
.divA{
width: 200vw;
height: 200vh;
overflow: hidden;
padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.divB{
position: absolute;
top: 20%;
left: 20%;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`overflow: hidden` doesn't prevent scrolling on that element. It specifies that content within the element [will be clipped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow#hidden) if it overflows the element.  Note that absolutely-positioned child elements are not considered part of the content of the parent.

Perhaps you want a container outside `divA` with `overflow: hidden`. This would prevent the user from scrolling `divA` even though it is larger than the display area.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.divA {
  width: 200vw;
  height: 200px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, black 0%, white 100%);
  ;
}

.divB {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 20%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.abs {
  position: absolute;
  background: green;
  left: 500px;
  top: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.rel {
  position: relative;
  background: blue;
  left: 300px;
  top: -50px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.ballast {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ballast">above</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="divA">
    <div class="divB"></div>

    <div class="abs"></div>
    <div class="rel"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="ballast">below</div>
```